# How to access a list element in a python object with getattr?

Tags: python, getattr

In python3 I have the following complete code:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = [42, 4711]
        self.y = [4, 6]
        self.z = 99

t = Test()
v = 'x[1]' # or can be 'y[0]' or can be 'z' ...
print(eval('t.'+v))
print(getattr(t,v))
```

which throws an error for the last line

```
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'x[1]'
```

Is there a way to access a list inside an object via `getattr`, or do I have to use `eval` in this case?

HINT: The index is part of the string! I do not know if the attribute I am about to access is a list or just a value, This need to work for the following cases:

```
v = 'x[0]'
v = 'x[1]'
v = 'y[0]'
v = 'z'
```

Comment: `getattr(Test(), 'x')`  is returning the list x, what do you want else?

Comment: I do not know if the object is a list at all. Also the index is part of the string 'v'.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use eval.

You can use `getattr` but you don't need the `.` nor the index in the string, just the attribute name.

```
t = Test()
v = 'x'
print(getattr(t, v)[0])
```

Outputs

```
42
```

This assumes that you actually need `v` to be a string (ie it comes from user input). Otherwise use the trivial way

```
print(t.x[0])
```

Comment: I do not know the index beforehand. I even do not know if the object is a list; see updated question.

Comment: @Alex Why don't you know? what are you not telling us? This feels like an XY problem. Either way, this is not possible out of the box without using `eval`, but you really don't want to use it. You may try to use a regex to search for `[\d]` in the string, and use the way I showed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need :

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = [42, 4711]
        self.y = [4, 6]
        self.z = 99

t = Test()

my_x = getattr(t,'x')
print(my_x) # output : [42, 4711]
print(my_x[1]) # output : 4711
```

Comment: The index is part of the string!

Comment: Maybe you could use 2 strings ? one with "x" and the second with "1" ? Can you tell us where the string comes from, the constraints you have, etc

Comment: Please assume it is a fundamental question -> I can do it with `eval` in the generic way depicted. Can I do the same with out `eval`?

Answer (score 0):

If the value is `str` you need to use `eval()`. You can override `__getattr__` in `Test` and use it there

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = [42, 4711]
        self.y = [4, 6]
        self.z = 99

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return eval('self.' + item)


t = Test()
v = 'x[1]'
print(getattr(t, v)) # 4711
```